# Is there a way to do multiple replaces one after another in C#?

Tags: c#

I am trying to duplicate javascript code that looks like this:

```
car = document.transcription.text1.value;
car = car.replace(/ん/g, "n");
car = car.replace(/つ/g, "tsu");
car = car.replace(/きゃ/g, "kya");
car = car.replace(/きゅ/g, "kyu");
car = car.replace(/きょ/g, "kyo");
...
```

There are at least another 50 replaces.

Is there a way for me to duplicate this functionality in C# by chaining one replace after another?

Comment: I don't know what is `car` , but did you try `car = car.replace(/ん/g, "n").replace(/つ/g, "tsu");`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is, you could use an extension method such as the following (if you need to use Regex such as for same expressions translating to the same letter sequence):

```
public static class RegexStringExtension
{
    public static String RegexReplace ( this String haystack, String regex, String replacement )
    {
        return new Regex ( regex ).Replace ( haystack, replacement );
    }
}
```

And then you could concat them like this (or just use normal Replace if they are all unique):

```
var car = // ... get the value somehow
car = car.RegexReplace ( "ん", "n" )
    .RegexReplace ( "つ", "tsu" )
    .RegexReplace ( "きゃ", "kya" )
    .RegexReplace ( "きゅ", "kyu" )
    .RegexReplace ( "きょ", "kyo" );
    // ... other replacements
```

I have tested the code and it seems to work: https://ideone.com/Yu7pUE

Answer (score 2):

At least you need to tell the compiler what should be replaced with what?

Declare a dictionary and mention it as

```
Dictionary<string, string> replaces = new Dictionary<string, string>() 
{ 
    {"old1", "new1"},
    {"old2", "new2"},
    {"old3", "new3"}
};
```

Then in a loop, you can do this as

```
foreach (var item in replaces)
{
    str.Replace(item.Key, item.Value);
}
```

Comment: Would not be nice if Regex supported function that called when match found to allow one to perform dictionary lookup? Unfortunately both JavaScript and C# support such method making quality of source code in the question... questionable?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: There is such a function, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy(v=vs.110).aspx, e.g. Regex.Replace(input, ".", match => dictionary.ContainsKey(match.Value) ? dictionary[match.Value] : match.Value)

Comment: @ckuri That would be extremely inefficient though (and also wouldn't work on OP's case, since it also has 2-letter cases) since a dictionary lookup would've to be made for **every** letter in the haystack (and a second when there is actually a match), and those aren't cheap.

Comment: True, I just showed the general procedure of using Regex.Replace with a dictionary lookup callback. In actual code one would of course need to restrict the pattern to valid values, e.g. "(んlつlきゃlきゅlきょl…)".

Answer (score 1):

`Replace` returns a `string` so keep calling `Replace` on the returned value like this:

```
var name = "How are you there buddy?";
name =
   name
      .Replace('H', '_')
      .Replace('o', '_')
      .Replace('w', '_');
```

---

**Another Approach**

**NOTE:** I think the first approach is simpler and more intuitive: Whether you use a dictionary or just a simple `Replace`, you still have to type up the replacing and replaced strings. You decide.

If you want to keep all the items to be replaced and the replacing items in a dictionary then you can use Linq's [Zip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx) method as well. Don't let the name throw you off because it has nothing to do with zipping as in zipping a file. It actually gets its name from how a zipper on clothes works. The zipper on clothes enumerates both sides of the zipper and either closes the teeth or opens the teeth one by one. That is exactly what `Zip` does also. You give it two `IEnumerable<T>`s and it will enumerate both of them and perform on operation during each enumeration. Here is how:

```
var name = "How are you there buddy?";
var replacer = new Dictionary<string, string>();
replacer.Add("H", "_");
replacer.Add("o", "-");
replacer.Add("e", "*");

var names = replacer.Zip(name, (x, y) => name = name.Replace(x.Key, x.Value))
   .Last();
```

This will be the output which is exactly what we expected:

```
_-w ar* y-u th*r* buddy?
```

Answer (score 0):

As a simple answer,

```
car = car.replace(/ん/g, "n").replace(/つ/g, "tsu").replace(/きゃ/g, "kya").replace(/きゅ/g, "kyu").replace(/きょ/g, "kyo")...;
```

Although for 50+ replaces, you may want to just make a dictionary or array or whatever and loop through it.